# Android Dark theme inverts colours of vector drawables

Tags: android, material-design, androidx, material-components-android

I'm using user profile avatars imported as vector drawables from an SVG file. I also extend my theme to the material theme `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`. However, when I switch to dark mode, the vector graphic inverts the colours and it looks awful.

There's a similar question on SO here:  [Why is Android inverting some of my drawables for dark theme (night) but not others?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63008623/3437352), which doesn't answer my question, because the applicable answer is for icons (and not graphics / illustrations).

**What am I looking for?**

Some kind of a manual override which prevents inverting of colours for vector drawables, since the colours are not a part of the material theming system. Also, it is not practical for me to put in all the possible colour shades from all the avatars into my `themes.xml`.

Example vector drawable avatar

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="128"
    android:viewportWidth="128" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="#a7aece" android:pathData="M64,64m-60,0a60,60 0,1 1,120 0a60,60 0,1 1,-120 0"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.3" android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M64,64m-48,0a48,48 0,1 1,96 0a48,48 0,1 1,-96 0" android:strokeAlpha="0.3"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#8f5653" android:pathData="M110.08,80.5l-0.88,-2.69c-2.89,-7.83 -17.3,-46.91 -17.78,-48l-0.5,-1.29H90.8a30,30 0,0 0,-53.6 0h-0.13l-0.52,1.36C35.51,32.44 19.07,77.1 19,77.42a47.49,47.49 0,0 0,-1.54 24.39,60 60,0 0,0 93.16,0 49.66,49.66 0,0 0,-0.5 -21.31Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#4bc190" android:pathData="M23.45,108.21a60,60 0,0 0,81.1 0,43.38 43.38,0 0,0 0.84,-29.09l-0.14,-0.46c-4.87,-13.2 -16.91,-45.81 -17.49,-47.22l-0.05,-0.1a26,26 0,0 0,-47.42 0l0,0.08c-0.57,1.38 -16.82,45.28 -17.5,47.26a43.4,43.4 0,0 0,0.7 29.52Z"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#f8dc25"
        android:pathData="M99.57,80.59C93.23,63.4 83,35.81 82.23,33.78a20,20 0,0 0,-36.46 0C44.63,36.72 29.1,78.67 28.44,80.59a37.42,37.42 0,0 0,7 36.2,60.05 60.05,0 0,0 57.06,0A37.41,37.41 0,0 0,99.66 80.9Z" android:strokeAlpha="0.5"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.3" android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M99.57,80.59C93.23,63.4 83,35.81 82.23,33.78a20,20 0,0 0,-36.46 0C44.63,36.72 29.1,78.67 28.44,80.59a37.42,37.42 0,0 0,7 36.2,60.05 60.05,0 0,0 57.06,0A37.41,37.41 0,0 0,99.66 80.9Z" android:strokeAlpha="0.3"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.5" android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M64,122A29.49,29.49 0,0 1,36 83.13c0.67,-1.93 15.5,-42 17.11,-46.24a12,12 0,0 1,21.72 0c1.07,2.79 9.4,25.32 17.13,46.26l0,0.12A29.49,29.49 0,0 1,64 122Z" android:strokeAlpha="0.5"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#515570" android:pathData="M64,92.5m-20.5,0a20.5,20.5 0,1 1,41 0a20.5,20.5 0,1 1,-41 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#393c54" android:pathData="M64,92.5m-11,0a11,11 0,1 1,22 0a11,11 0,1 1,-22 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M79.66,56.5m-7.49,0a7.49,7.49 0,1 1,14.98 0a7.49,7.49 0,1 1,-14.98 0"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.2" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M48.34,68a11.46,11.46 0,0 1,-9.1 -4.48"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.2" android:strokeColor="#515570"
        android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.2" android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:pathData="M79.84,68a11.52,11.52 0,0 0,9.85 -5.56"
        android:strokeAlpha="0.2" android:strokeColor="#515570"
        android:strokeLineCap="round" android:strokeLineJoin="round" android:strokeWidth="2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="M48.34,56.5m-7.49,0a7.49,7.49 0,1 1,14.98 0a7.49,7.49 0,1 1,-14.98 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#f85565" android:pathData="M64,113A20.49,20.49 0,0 0,84.13 96.3,22.3 22.3,0 0,0 72,93.17c-0.54,0 -1.08,0 -1.63,0.11A2.07,2.07 0,0 0,68.63 95a1.2,1.2 0,0 1,-1.81 0.67A3.12,3.12 0,0 0,63.87 95a22.58,22.58 0,0 0,-12.49 13.66A20.36,20.36 0,0 0,64 113Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#393c54" android:pathData="M79.66,56.5m-4.09,0a4.09,4.09 0,1 1,8.18 0a4.09,4.09 0,1 1,-8.18 0"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#393c54" android:pathData="M48.34,56.5m-4.09,0a4.09,4.09 0,1 1,8.18 0a4.09,4.09 0,1 1,-8.18 0"/>
    <path android:fillAlpha="0.2" android:fillColor="#fff"
        android:pathData="M68.29,95.5a1.16,1.16 0,0 1,-1.47 0.13,4.87 4.87,0 0,0 -0.59,-0.36c0.43,3.56 1.66,9.24 5.21,13.08a1,1 0,0 0,0.73 0.32,1 1,0 0,0 0.68,-0.27 1,1 0,0 0,0.06 -1.41C69.91,103.75 68.74,98.81 68.29,95.5Z" android:strokeAlpha="0.2"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#4bc190" android:pathData="M61.68,59.51 L60,64.28A2,2 0,0 0,61.93 67h4.19a2,2 0,0 0,1.93 -2.72l-1.67,-4.77A2.49,2.49 0,0 0,61.68 59.51Z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#8f5653" android:pathData="M61.68,59.51 L60,64.28A2,2 0,0 0,61.93 67h4.19a2,2 0,0 0,1.93 -2.72l-1.67,-4.77A2.49,2.49 0,0 0,61.68 59.51Z"/>
</vector>
```

**Update:** As an interim fix, I've duplicated all my avatar drawables into `drawable-night`; but that seems like an inefficient solution to me.

Comment: How exactly are your profile avatar vector drawables defined?

Comment: @Edric It is simply imported to Android studio from an SVG file. I've added a sample avatar in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this to the XML

```
android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
```

Comment: This is not possible since the SVG is an illustration (with multiple colors) and not an icon.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the color of your vector in colors.xml file in both values & values-night folder with same name and then just set the tint of your vector to that color.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But, the issue with that approach was that the I've 50+ vector drawables (these are illustrated avatars) and each one of them has multiple hard-coded colours (as shown in the sample drawable in the question)

Answer (score 0):

The spontaneous solution that worked for me:

in html:

```
<img src="logo.svg">
```

and for logo.svg file:

```
<svg style="color-scheme: dark;">
    ...
</svg>
```